# How to recover from system hang safely with no keyboard response?

Tags: linux, firefox, fedora, crash

My computer system hangs once in a blue moon when I am surfing certain websites such as *Yahoo*. The whole screen would freeze, except for the mouse pointer which I can still move around. It doesn't seem to respond to any keyboard inputs and mouse clicks. Is there a way to **safely** recover from this situation short of hitting the reset button, which I think isn't as safe?

Comment: Have a system monitoring software run in the background so that you can see if the CPU or RAM usage spikes during that. Also, hit `Ctrl+Print+K` to restart the X-Server.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "safe"?...i have hit the reset button a 100 times...